# Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Cake'. how to fix it

Tags: typescript

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Cake } from './model/cake';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      cake = Cake;

      constructor() {
        this.cake = new Cake('Black Forest', 'This is awasome cake', null, null, null);
      }
    }

   this is error-
```

> ERROR in C:/xampp/htdocs/cakeshop/src/app/app.component.ts (14,5):
>   Type 'Cake' is not assignable to type 'typeof Cake'.   Property
>   'prototype' is missing in type 'Cake'.
>
> cake class properties

```
export interface Ingredient {
    ingredient: string;
    measure: string;
}

export interface Instruction {
    instruction: string;
    photo: string;
}
export class Cake {
    public title: string;
    public description: string;
    public ingredient: Ingredient[];
    public instruction: Instruction[];
    public cover_photo: string;
    constructor(t: string, d: string, ing: Ingredient[], ins: Instruction[], cp: string) {
        this.title = t;
        this.description = d;
        this.ingredient = ing;
        this.instruction = ins;
        this.cover_photo = cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your Cake class code with properties in question

Comment: plz suggest asap

Comment: Cake is class, either make it with new Cake(), or use it as interface, cake: Cake.